# Vue3 - i18n - You are running the esm-bundler build of vue-i18n

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, i18next, vue-i18n

I have just started a new project with Vue3 and added `vue-i18n` version 9 (https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/)
I have set up, but I can't change the language. It's doing the trasnlation since it's changing the `{{ $t('message.value') }}` to the proper sentence.
I'm unable to change the language, only works for the locale language.

I'm receiving this error message in the browser console

```
You are running the esm-bundler build of vue-i18n. It is recommended to configure your bundler to explicitly replace feature flag globals with boolean literals to get proper tree-shaking in the final bundle.
```

This is my config, but I can't change it to Spanish

```
const i18n = VueI18n.createI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  fallbackLocale: 'en', // set fallback locale
  messages, // set locale messages

})
```

I would appreciate if you could help me, showing me what I am doing wrong.
Many thanks

Comment: It's working properly and changing the language, but would be nice to know what to do with the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't see it when running your app in production mode.

When running in development it had been corrected in version  [v2.0.1](https://github.com/intlify/vue-cli-plugin-i18n/releases/tag/v2.0.1)